# Magento Get Max entity_id from sales_flat_order_status_history

Tags: magento-enterprise

The following code does not give me any output.

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status_history')->getCollection()->getLastItem();
    print_r($collection->getData());
```

I have SQL Query for this but I have to use magento collection for this.

```
   SELECT MAX(entity_id) AS entity_id FROM sales_flat_order_status_history
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Try using an expression. You will have more control over what you're attempting to query.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status_history')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToSelect(new Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(entity_id) AS entity_id'))
    ->getFirstItem()
;

$maxEntityId = $collection->getData('entity_id');
```

Comment: MAX(entity_id) is much more efficient than setOrder , as it is much less ressource intensive for the database engine. So, even if it seems less beautiful to have some pure SQL bits wrapped by a Zend DB Expr, it will be much better to use daXXon's solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status_history')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->order('entity_id DESC');
    $collection->setPageSize(1);
    $maxId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
```

Comment: Who marked my post for deletion - please leave your feedback

Comment: This will load the ENTIRE `sales/order_status_history` table and then get the first item of the underlying `Varien_Collection`. Add `->setPageSize(1)` to the collection to `LIMIT` the query.

Comment: Good stuff!....

Comment: While this works, ordering is much more resource consuming for a database than the SQL MAX  function itself

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setOrder('Index','Order')` function for getting max data

```
 $maxData=Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_history_collection')
                  ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')->getFirstItem()

print_r( $maxData->getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection->addExpressionFieldToSelect("max_id", "MAX(entity_id)", [])
->getFirstItem()
->getData("max_id");
```